# “VBA Loop Until - Array” I want to get out as soon as the array is filled

Tags: arrays, vba

I’m struggling with arrays.

Well, I’m trying to finish a loop when the array is assigned with values.

So, I tried a number of methods including this one;

```
Sub Testing()
 Dim Pair1() As Variant
 Dim pair11 As String
 Dim NofDays As Long
 pair11 = "ABC"
 NofDays = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Count
 ReDim Pair1(1 To NofDays)
    Do
        If Selection = pair11 Then
            Pair1 = Range(Selection.Offset(1, 0), Selection.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
        End If
        If IsEmpty(Pair1) = False Then Exit Do
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop Until Selection.Value = ""

End Sub
```

**Pair1** is a dynamic array, and the size is already known while no value has been assigned to the array.

What is really annoying is this part

**If IsEmpty(Pair1) = False Then Exit Do**

And I put this IsEmpty function to get out of the loop, to avoid unnecessary loops.
BUT! **Although the array Pair1 is not filled at all (even one value), this exits the loop.**
I think there’s something that I missed out..

Anyone can help me?

thank you in advance!

Comment: There's a few more things wrong with this code than the array... is ABC a variable, or is it meant to be "ABC"? NofDays is referring to range A2, but within the selection object -is the selection necessary there? Then the loop..what exactly is it trying to do? it tests to match a value, and if it does, it assigns cells values (hopefully) to an array, then you test the whole array to see if it's empty, and leave if it is, otherwise you offset the selection, retest. If selection<>pair11 (which is in turn empty, and hard to match) pair1 will always be empty, and the loop will exit.

Comment: @ Rowan; Oh, sorry I just slipped over some wrongs on it, and fixed them up. ABC is "ABC", a string. When pair11 is equal to the selection value, then Pair1, the array, will be filled up. you've understood clearly. What I want to focus is 'If IsEmpty(Pair1) = **False** Then Exit Do'.  If The Pair1 is not empty (meaning pair11 found the corresponding cell, and Pair1 gets filled), and 'If IsEmpty(Pair1) = **False**' this condition will be met, and the loop's terminated. BUT! _Why is 'IsEmpty(Pair1) = **False**' not working?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is IsEmpty(Pair1) = False not working?

`IsEmpty` doesn't test whether an array is allocated (i.e., the array is populated with at least one value(s)).  It tests the allocation of numeric data, i.e.,:

```
Dim i as Integer
Debug.Print IsEmpty(i) 'Should say "True"

i = 6

Debug.Print IsEmpty(i) 'Should now say "False"
```

So while the array is not `Empty` in this sense, that doesn't mean what you think it means :)

There are at least two ways I think of to handle this for you.

**Option One**  Just put the `Exit Do` statement *inside* the `If/Then` block that allocates a value to `Pair1`, because at this point you **know with 100% certainty** that the array has been allocated a value.

```
    If Selection = pair11 Then
        Pair1 = Range(Selection.Offset(1, 0), Selection.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
        Exit Do
    End If
```

**Option Two** Use it as an additional constraing on the Loop logic. Use the `UBound` function to determine the *upper bound* of the array. An initialized but unpopulated array with unspecified dimension should ordinarily have a `UBound` of `-1`.  Once you assign values to it, the `Ubound` will represent the last index of the array items, so any value greater than or equal to zero will mean that there are values in the array.

```
Do
    If Selection = pair11 Then
        Pair1 = Range(Selection.Offset(1, 0), Selection.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
    End If
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop While Not Selection.Value = "" OR Ubound(Pair1) >= 0
```

I would personally probably use Option 1 because to me it is easier to understand and I think it flows better than nested logic in the loop controller. But YMMV and either method I think should work.

Comment: Well, I came across the error message "Ubound(Pair1): Subscript Out of Range" when I was trying the option two. If I want to go for the option 2, then should I not do "ReDim Pair1(1 To NofDays)"? If I don't Re-dim the array, then the error message "Subscript Out of Range"

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use a `ReDim` statement on this. When you initialize the variable `pair1() As Variant` it will *automatically* take on the size of the range defined by `Range(Selection.Offset(1,0)....` regardless of whether you `ReDim` to that exact size (or to a different size).  That said, I'm not able to replicate either error you're having. Did option 1 work? If so perhaps that is easier. If not, you should revise your question or even ask a new one since this is technically a "new" problem.

Comment: Dear Mr. David, Thank you so much for your explanation. I've got another problem when following your method. I didn't Redim the arrays (Pair1 and Pair2) but another error arises on `Loop While Not Selection.Value = "" OR Ubound(Pair1) >= 0`, especially `Ubound(Pair1) >= 0`. It says `<Subscript out of range>`.

Comment: why don't you just use the first option then?

Comment: Or instead of `UBound(pair1) >= 0` maybe `Len(Join(pair1,",")) > 0`.

Comment: Haha, Yes I did! that works perfectly. thank you so much! have a lovely weekend!